# Getting selected value from multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

If user change the entry from any dropdowns in the `SalePlugin` div then it will need to get all the selected value and pass it into POST.

How it should be done?

```
$('.SalePlugin > *').live('change', function(){
 var SalePluginData = $(this).closest('.SalePlugin').find('select').serialize();
 $.post(host + '/ajax/file.php', { Data: SalePluginData }, function(data){
            console.log(data);
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='SalePlugin'> 
 <ul>
   <li> 
      <select name='something[]'> 
        <option value='one'>One</option>
        <option value='two'>Two</option>
      </select> 
    </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li> 
      <select name='something[]'> 
        <option value='one'>One</option>
        <option value='two'>Two</option>
      </select> 
    </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li> 
      <select name='foo[]'> 
        <option value='one'>One</option>
        <option value='two'>Two</option>
      </select> 
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

To get the selected items in a dropdownlist use this

```
$(".SalePlugin option:selected");
```

this 'll get the selected items.  You can store them in array or make a loop and do whatever you want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".SalePlugin option:selected").length; i++) {
    values[i] = $($(".SalePlugin option:selected")[i]).attr('value');
}
```